# Get 60 json files of 10 MB per file every 10 hours on Azure using Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure

I am running a node.js application on Azure and I am new to Azure. Currently, I am using the setInterval() to fetch 60 REST API endpoints every 10 hours that give me  a JSON file. I am storing these files on the local filesystem. All this works perfectly on my localhost. However how do I achieve this on Azure? I read about the scheduler and while it gets results , it seems to have an 8MB limit on the body if I am not mistaken. What would be the right way to accomplish this using Azure and what is the difference between setInterval() and Azure scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [**WebJobs**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/). 
You [cron](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-Jobs#scheduling-a-triggered-webjob) that thing every 10 hours and you're done.

```
{
    "schedule": "0 0 */10 * * *"
}
```

You can use Node or you could simply do a `curl`:

```
curl.exe -O http://example.com/api/some_json
```

Comment: thanks for the link, i went through it, from what i see it simply lets you run a https rest request with a cron syntax but what about saving the results, does it also handle that

Comment: You handle that in your code. The WebJob's only task is to run your code either continuously or on a cron-style defined schedule.

Comment: Here's a video to clear things up - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/azure-webjobs-cross-platform/